# Deployments: MSI packages vs Scripts

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

I have been tasked with looking into our deployments, and seeing where they can be streamlined. Right now we have 4 different configurations (Debug/Dev, Test, Staging, Release) and 4 *.config files. We have a task that will overwrite app/web.config with the appropriate *.config pre-build time based on the active configuration. An MSI is created, and we do a full deployment of the component on release night.

This is not entirely ideal because if we change something in a config file, or fix the spelling in a specific view we have to re-deploy the entire thing. Not to metion that the MSI will occasionally require a reboot. One other option that has been brought up is instead of creating MSIs we could create custom deployment/rollback scripts and have the ability to do incremental release.

Has anyone here tried deployments both ways? What are some of the pros/cons you have found? Is there a third way we haven't thought of?

**edit:** Just to clarify a few things...We don't deploy to customers. All software is deployed to our servers. (a few sites, and a lot of windows services). We never change things in production. We actually use the built in system within VS to create the MSI, so that part isn't the terrible part. To me it just doesn't make sense to redeploy an entire website if you had to change 1 view. We also have to deploy to multiple servers. Right now that is done by running the MSI on each one.

Comment: Having touched on this kind of thing myself, I found it extremely f@@@ing painful, so will watch this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI pros:

- Application/service/site gets installed and registered like most other Windows apps, and shows up in Add/Remove programs
- Some built-in support for re-installing, upgrading
- Has some built-in support for installing Windows services/IIS sites/lower-level Windows features

MSI cons:

- Seems really cryptic once you get "under the hood"
- Seems more difficult to customize than using a custom script

Script pros:

- Easier to customize, although certain steps might require lots of/cryptic scripting (working with IIS, lower-level computer administration)
- Don't have to deal with low-level weirdness of MSI

Script cons:

- .bat scripting is not the most readable or writable language.  (Powershell is better, but then you have to worry about whether Powershell is installed on the target machine).
- Low-level operations require a lot of administrative scripting for commit/rollback behavior
- No built in support for installing or rolling-back (MSI has some support built-in)

One thing I've come across that helps with MSIs is WiX (http://wix.sourceforge.net/), but even WiX seems pretty cryptic in a lot of ways.  We use a combination of MSBuild and WiX to do automated builds and deployment/installs, and it works okay for us.

Overall, I'd probably lean more towards doing MSI/WiX (or other installer toolkit) deployments over scripts.  MSIs are the standard way of doing installs on Windows, and once you get it working, you usually don't have to change too much.  MSBuild or some other build framework (NAnt, etc.), can be useful for setting up the deployment (renaming files, doing string replacements, etc.), before putting together the final MSI package.

Answer (score 1):

Running a dev company that build web apps for five years we struggled with this and tried a bunch of solutions. Here are a couple tips:

- Always replace the entire web directory with your code (except if you have content generated by the web site, like a CMS). It's pretty fast to do this and incremental deployments can introduce phantom bugs if files are left around.
- Have your build process (Nant, MSBuild, whatever) mod the .config files for each environment and build for what you push for. Alternately you can use registry settings so that the .config files are the same but that means a dedicated machine for each environment. May or may not be an issue.
- Don't make changes in production. If you need to make changes (spelling errors on site) make those top priority to get changed in dev so that you don't overwrite them with the next push.
- If you aren't using MSI's then make sure you have a rollback process. Keeping a copy of the site just before you changed it really helps when something unexplained goes sideways during a roll-out.

I don't know that these tips point to MSI or script. I think it's a matter of which you are most comfortable with. MSI's can be hard to customize, but easy to run and manage. Microsoft has lots of tools for managing roll-outs of MSI's across an organization or farm. Scripts may require custom tools and custom tooling or lots of manual work on the production end.

We ran scripts with Nant and a custom deployment harness. These days (VS2008) building deployment packages is much easier.

Comment: +1 for some of those tips - i found partial updates of a web app using msi always caused issues (files not being correctly replaced etc), so now i always replace everything except the web.config file (that is updated independantly).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to get a decent MSI builder to do the job with - i'm talking about InstallShield etc (there are a couple, so do look around). While these invariably cost, they can save you a huge amount of time/money/pain further down the track. Having said that, the pain is not totally eliminated, just reduced :)

Anything tricky you need to do can be done as a custom task within the msi - and you can even do this with the setup builder that comes with Visual Studio (if you are using VS).

I have a suggestion for your config files - include all four in the msi, and then have a public property which can be set from the command line. You can then modify that public property to install the appropriate config file (and have the default value of that property set so that the release config gets installed). That way, your customers just use the msi and get the correct config file, but your test team can get their config file by changing the value of the public property; the command line they would use to do the install is this:

```
msiexec /i "MyInstaller.msi" CONFIG=test
```

You can do install scripts quite easily, but as already mentioned you also need to script the uninstall. Using install scripts precludes you from getting Windows certification for your product should you look at getting that done. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't use install scripts, they may be the perfect fit for your needs. Alternatively you may look at using a combined script/msi approach by having your scripts run as custom actions from within the msi.